# SecurityNegotiationException in WCF/TLS service only on high latency network

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, networking, latency

I try to make a WCF web-service work on a high latency / low bandwidth network and things don't work as planned.
The WCF service is self-hosted in a windows service, implementing this interface :

```
[OperationContract(Name = "send-file")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void SendFile(MyFileInfo myFile);
```

MyFileInfo objects contain the file (as a byte array). The file is around 45 kB (kilobytes).

TLS is in use, with both client and server authentication (certificates from the same CA, clients and server from the same domain).

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is set to SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 on both clients and server, Expect100Continue is set true, and KeepAlive is programmatically set to true on the binding transport element.

App.config is here (same for clients and server) :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyHttpsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" messageEncoding="Text"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
            textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" ></message>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service 
        name="MyService" 
        behaviorConfiguration="MyHttpsBehavior">
            <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="MyHttpsBinding" name="MyEndpoint"
            contract="IMyInterface">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyHttpsBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
                    </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Everything works fine on a standard local network (WLAN or ethernet, MTU is always set to 1248), but I get errors when I switch to a (simulated) high latency / low bandwidth network :

- 800ms latency, inbound and outbound. That makes a 1.6sc way and back
  trip.
- 492 Kbps (kilobits, not bytes).
- MTU = 1248

At first, my app.conf timeout settings were set to 1 minute and the client threw a solid System.TimeoutException : *"The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.1535069. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'https://myserver:4444/' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."*

No error on the server.

If I do the math, file is 45 kb = 46080 b ~> 37 packets (MTU & fragmentation) => 37 * 1600 (latency) = 1 minute minimum (plus TLS, plus payload, plus...)

I changed the timeout settings on clients and server to 5 minutes, and a new client exception popped : *"System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'myserver:4444'"*

Client and server can be Windows 8 or Windows 2008 R2, firewalls are down, and if I stop the latency simulator (Clumsy), everything works fine again.

I smell a TLS problem more than a WCF one, but I'm no expert. Maybe one of you has an idea on this issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Dj

**EDIT**
I tried a Wireshark session (client view) and here are the results :

```
2  26.958440 client -> server  TCP 66 64972 → 4444 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1208 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
3  26.958603  server -> client TCP 66 4444 → 64972 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
4  28.606141 client -> server  TCP 54 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66304 Len=0
5  28.606359 client -> server  TCP 276 64972 → 4444 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66304 Len=222
6  28.610326  server -> client TCP 1262 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=223 Win=66304 Len=1208
7  28.610328  server -> client TCP 711 4444 → 64972 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1209 Ack=223 Win=66304 Len=657
8  30.277053 client -> server  TCP 54 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=223 Ack=1866 Win=61440 Len=0
9  30.277177 client -> server  TCP 236 64972 → 4444 [PSH, ACK] Seq=223 Ack=1866 Win=61440 Len=182
10  30.279375  server -> client TCP 161 4444 → 64972 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1866 Ack=405 Win=66048 Len=107
11  31.920922 client -> server  TCP 331 64972 → 4444 [PSH, ACK] Seq=405 Ack=1973 Win=61440 Len=277
12  31.921599  server -> client TCP 139 4444 → 64972 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1973 Ack=682 Win=65792 Len=85
13  32.249867 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=682 Ack=1973 Win=61440 Len=1208
14  32.250099 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=1890 Ack=1973 Win=61440 Len=1208
15  32.250226  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=3098 Win=66304 Len=0
16  32.250437 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=3098 Ack=1973 Win=61440 Len=1208
17  32.250699 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=4306 Ack=1973 Win=61440 Len=1208
18  32.250816  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=5514 Win=66304 Len=0
19  33.623716 client -> server  TCP 54 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=5514 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=0
... lots of similar packets ...
89  37.189910 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=61082 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=1208
90  37.190103 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=62290 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=1208
91  37.190260  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=63498 Win=53760 Len=0
92  37.190303 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=63498 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=1208
93  37.190499 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [ACK] Seq=64706 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=1208
94  37.190654  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=65914 Win=51200 Len=0
95  37.190699 client -> server  TCP 1262 64972 → 4444 [PSH, ACK] Seq=65914 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=1208
96  37.190890 client -> server  TCP 865 64972 → 4444 [PSH, ACK] Seq=67122 Ack=2058 Win=61440 Len=811
97  37.191046  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=67933 Win=49152 Len=0
98 160.241458  server -> client TCP 60 4444 → 64972 [RST, ACK] Seq=2058 Ack=67933 Win=0 Len=0
```

The 98 packet (RST ACK) pops at the exact same time as my exception on the client. Still no errors on the server.

Comment: Update : if I disable TLS, everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't have the time to investigate further and I still don't know why mutual authentication does not work, but if I disable client certificate, everything works fine again. Problem (almost) solved...